# If I want to build a railgun, how do I calculate the length of the rails?

Tags: capacitor

I want to build a railgun, but I find it difficult to calculate the length of the rails, since the acceleration is not uniform, due to the voltage's decreasing when the capacitors discharges. Neither do I know the way to calculate the curve of the capacitor's discharging. I plan to use 6 fully charged 1000uf 450v capacitors as the energy source, giving 1215 Joules of energy.
The projectile will be a 7mm steel ball weighting around 1.4g.
The rails will be copper cylinders, 10mm in diameter. The current in the rails will also create the magnetic field.
How long should the rails be?

Comment: How long should they be to do what? First you might want to calculate the energy needed to do whatever you want it to do and compare that to the energy and probable efficiency

Comment: To get most of the capacitors' energy transferred to the steel ball's kinetic energy

Comment: @Howkong: aint going to happen. You would be extremely lucky to get even 1% of the energy transferred.

Comment: Thanks. Another question, I was told that the projectile might me "welded" to the rails, how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

The force available to accelerate the projectile decreases over time and distance. At the same time, the deceleration forces are increasing (friction with the rails, air resistance, etc.) You need to find the crossover point where the net force drops to zero, and have the rails end somewhat before that point. That's where you'll have the greatest "muzzle velocity".

Comment: Very instructive

Answer (score 0):

You don't calculate the length of the rails. You build the biggest one you have room or materials for, experiment with it for a while, then build a bigger one!

Alternatively you find (or write) a railgun simulator, and run it with various lengths of rail. That is a somewhat cheaper approach. You **will** be doing a simulation first, won't you? Or were you intending to go straight for cutting metal?

Comment: Where can I find one? Most of those sort of softwares are coilgun simulations instead of railgun simulations.

Comment: Or how do I calculate that discharging curve, in order to write one?

Comment: Capacitor discharge curve is basic math. Google it.

Comment: You don't calculate the capacitor discharge curve, because it is affected by the acceleration of the projectile. To simulate what's happening, you solve a series of small equations per timestep, so current = last current + V/L, velocity = last velocity + force/mass, and so on.